# Use variable within JMeter $__timeshift

Tags: variables, time, jmeter, shift

I have a variable which is a date in the format of yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'

I am trying to use timeshift to minus 1 day from that date - ${date_var}

I've tried the following, but it doesnt seem to take the ${date_var}, and instead returns a date of minus 1 day, from the current date/time.

${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z',${date_var},-P1D,,newdate)}

Any ideas how to input a variable into the timeshift?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is absolutely correct:

[image]

If you're not getting the same output there could be 2 possibilities:

1. Your `${date_var}` variable value isn't matching `yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'` [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) pattern, if this is the case - the relevant error will be posted to [jmeter.log file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/)
2. If you're using [The Function Helper Dialog](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper) for testing be aware that it doesn't resolve any JMeter Varibles because JMeter Variables live in thread (virtual user) context, you can only use JMeter Properties there

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if its worked for you either? If you re-run that but set ${date_var} to a different date other than todays date, or different to when you run it, it might be more clear. Reason I say this is because you seconds are out.

Comment: Well, it looks like a bug in the function which should be reported via [JMeter Bugzilla](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html). In the meantime you can use the alternative solution assuming __groovy() function: `${__groovy(vars.put('newdate'\, new Date().parse('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ss\'Z\''\, vars.get('date_var')).minus(1).format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ss\'Z\'')),)}`t